# How can you use Javascript to duplicate a JSON object based on the value of a key in the object?

Tags: javascript

Considering the following JSON object example as input, how would you use Javascript to duplicate each object based on the number of times found in the "Count" key/value pair?

Example Input:

```json
[
  { "name":"David", "Count":2 },
  { "name":"John", "Count":3 },
]
```

Expected Output:

```json
[
  { "name": "David" },
  { "name": "David" },
  { "name": "John" },
  { "name": "John" },
  { "name": "John" },
]
```

Comment: Homework time - [No effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341) - this is not the purpose of this site. We are happy to answer programming/debugging questions about code you have written. Give this a try, come back with some code that doesn't work and we'll help you out.

Comment: If not homework, then this seems highly likely an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with `reduce()` function:

```js
let data = [
  { "name": "David", "Count": 2 },
  { "name": "John", "Count": 3 },
]

let new_data = data.reduce((sum, current) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < current.Count; index++) {
    sum.push({ name: current.name })
  };
  return sum
}, []);

console.log(new_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the `Count` property and push into another array.

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "David",
    "Count": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "Count": 3
  }
];

const output = [];

data.forEach(({ name, Count}) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
    output.push({ name });
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you @GenericUser . Do you foresee any issues with doing this for things that might result in a large number of new objects in the array? Maybe something that results in a million objects?

Comment: @dwags - the issues will emerge when you move from a simplistic (unrealistic) contrived view of this to a real-world one.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - no this actually was super helpful and worked great to put me on the right path.

Comment: @dwags - OK, good news. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that

```js
const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => [
    ...acc,
    ...Array.from({length: cur.Count}).map(() => ({ name: cur.name })
], [])
```